# Rails 4/Devise 3.00rc/pg "Unpermitted parameters" in signup/edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm new to Rails -- using Rails 4 final with devise 3.0.0rc (rails 4 compatible). I configured both appropriately and signup was working properly, however at some point I started getting a Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name error when trying to create a new user (or edit an existing user's profile). There are some similar questions about this topic but for unsupported versions of Devise -- and my configuration was working properly initially.

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+DG4aeMPteQ4Mq9pPJ2JaitTVgp0NCW9nXi2qSv23zw=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Kenn", "email"=>"me1@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign Up"}
Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'me1@email.com' LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobrecords, dependent: :destroy

  # after_create :send_welcome_email

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  validates :first_name,  presence: true
  validates :last_name,   presence: true
  validates :email,       presence: true
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me


  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.first_name = auth.info.nickname
      user.last_name = auth.info.nickname
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session["devise.user_attributes"]
      new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true) do |user|
        user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end    
  end

  def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end

  def update_with_password(params, *options)
    if encrypted_password.blank?
      update_attributes(params, *options)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  private

    def send_welcome_email
      UserMailer.signup_confirmation(self).deliver
    end

end
```

Even though it was working properly before, I tried overriding sign_up_params in the registrations_controller.rb, but that did not work. I'm still able to sign up using openauth-twitter (since the app doesn't ask for a first or last name when signing up through twitter). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

So, I don't know if you've tried this yet, but I had a similar issue and I ended up adding the 'configure_permitted_parameters' method to my ApplicationController and added a devise_parameter_sanitizer for :sign_up and for :account_update, per this piece of the Devise docs: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Hopefully if this isn't exactly what you need, it will get you moving in the right direction.